# (R) My graph with multiple datasets only shows a few of the colors I code for?

Tags: r, graph, colors

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHEcI.png)**Summarize the problem**
I'm making a graph with multiple datasets that need to be different colors. For instance, I specify 8 colors in the code below, but all the lines only appear in 2 colors.

**Describe what you’ve tried**
This is my code specific to choosing colors. (Device.Name) is the independent variable I'm going with to display different datasets. onlyrecent$Delta_mm1 and onlyrecent$Delta_mm2 are converted y-axis values plotted as lines.

```
z <- cumdata$Device.Name

points(onlyrecent$YYYY.MM.DD.HH.MM.SS, onlyrecent$Delta_mm1,
      col = c(1, 3, 5, 7)[z], pch = 20, cex = 0.20)

points(onlyrecent$YYYY.MM.DD.HH.MM.SS, onlyrecent$Delta_mm2,
       col = c(2, 4, 6, 8)[z], pch = 20, cex = 0.25)
```

Comment: I don't understan why you are using `points` if you want `lines`. And you do realize I hope that you would need to initialize a base graphics effort with a call to `plot`, correct?

Comment: Sorry, I misstated. I've been thinking of lines so long that I forgot my data is just many points that look like a line together. I don't quite understand your 2nd point about the call to 'plot'.

Comment: Both `points` and `lines` are functions that add to an existing plot. You cannot start a graphics effort with either one of them. See `?plot` for how to set up a plot session.

Comment: Yes, I do have an existing plot function. This is just the code that is specific to designing the colors of the different datasets graphed.

Comment: I do have a plot function, or else I wouldn't have the problematic plot attached as an image in the embedded link. In that image, I hope you can see my problem better. I code for 8 different colors, but I only see 2 among all the datasets graphed.

Comment: The plotrix package has a multi-color line function. Your question doesn't have enough data or description of the problem to support a coded answer. Use SO's question [edit] facilities to improve the question body. DO NOT use comments.

Comment: Apologies, thank you. I'm new to this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+base+graphics+color+points

Comment: Greetings! Usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here rather than links or images. One way of doing this is by using the `dput` function. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg